# Need Faster Word Builder Algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, simplecursoradapter

I have an app that assists studying for Scrabble. Most searches are much faster than by desktop version in C#, except the Word Builder. This search shows all the words that can be formed from a given set of letters A-Z, or blanks.
What can I do to get it to run faster?
I've considered using a Trie, but haven't found a way to support the use of blanks.
I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate the ListView, which is why I am returning a cursor.

```
    public Cursor getCursor_subanagrams(String term, String filters, String ordering) {
    if (term.trim() == "")
        return null;
    // only difference between this and anagram is changing the length filter
    char[] a = term.toCharArray(); // anagram

    int[] first = new int[26]; // letter count of anagram
    int c; // array position
    int blankcount = 0;

    // initialize word to anagram
    for (c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
        if (a[c] == '?') {
            blankcount++;
            continue;
        }
        first[a[c] - 'A']++;
    }

// gets pool of words to search through
    String lenFilter = String.format("Length(Word) <= %1$s AND Length(Word) <= %2$s", LexData.getMaxLength(), term.length());
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT WordID as _id, Word, WordID, FrontHooks, BackHooks, " +
            "InnerFront, InnerBack, Anagrams, ProbFactor, OPlayFactor, Score \n" +
            "FROM     `" + LexData.getLexName() + "` \n" +
            "WHERE (" + lenFilter +
            filters +
            " ) " + ordering, null);

// creates new cursor to add valid words to
    MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "Word", "WordID", "FrontHooks", "BackHooks", "InnerFront", "InnerBack",
            "Anagrams", "ProbFactor", "OPlayFactor", "Score"});

// THIS NEEDS TO BE FASTER
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String word = cursor.getString(1);
        char[] b = word.toCharArray();
        if (isAnagram(first, b, blankcount)) {
            matrixCursor.addRow(get_CursorRow(cursor));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return matrixCursor;
}


private boolean isAnagram(int[] anagram, char[] word, int blankcount) {
    int matchcount = blankcount;
    int c; // each letter
    int[] second = {0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0, 0};

    for (c = 0; c < word.length; c++)
        second[word[c] - 'A']++;

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
    {
        matchcount += (anagram[c]<second[c]) ? anagram[c]:second[c];
    }

    if (matchcount == word.length)
        return true;
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Try doing all the "non UI" work on a separate thread, if you're not doing it already.

Comment: This is running in a separate thread. I just need it to run faster. Similar apps do this in about a tenth of the time, though they generally only show the word without details.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on speeding up the most typical case, which is where the word is not a (sub)anagram, and you return false. If you can identify as quickly as possible when it is not possible to make `word` out of `anagram` then you can avoid the expensive test.

One way to do this is using a bitmask of the letters in the words. You don't need to store letter counts, because if the number of unique letters in `word` that are not in `anagram` is greater than the number of blanks, then there is no way you can make it and you can quickly return false. If not then you can proceed to the more expensive test taking letter counts into account.

You can precompute the bitmasks like this:

```
private int letterMask(char[] word)
{
    int c, mask = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < word.length; c++)
        mask |= (1 << (word[c] - 'A'));
    return mask;
}
```

Add an extra column to your database to store the letter bitmask for each word, add it to your cursor, and compute the letter bitmask for the letters in `term` and store in `termMask`. Then inside your cursor loop you can do a test like this:

```
// compute mask of bits in mask that are not in term:
int missingLettersMask = cursor.getInt(8) & ~termMask;
if(missingLettersMask != 0)
{
    // check if we could possibly make up for these letters using blanks:
    int remainingBlanks = blankcount;
    while((remainingBlanks-- > 0) && (missingLettersMask != 0))
        missingLettersMask &= (missingLettersMask - 1); // remove one bit

    if(missingLettersMask != 0)
        continue; // move onto the next word
}

// word can potentially be made from anagram, call isAnagram:
```

Comment: Well, I tried that. After correcting cursor.getInt(8) to use the right column cursor.getInt(11), I got it to work.

Comment: Except it actually takes longer. To verify the proper execution of the code, I logged the "candidate" words that were passed to isAnagram() and the mask does filter out the words correctly.

Comment: That's a bit disappointing. Perhaps it is that database cursor functions that account for a lot of the time taken, and not your isAnagram() function.

Comment: Do you get much of a speed up by removing the ordering clause?

Comment: The database cursor shouldn't be taking much time. Other searches with simpler filtering methods return the same number of results quickly.
The ordering clause is also SQL so it takes practically no time.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to speed up your anagram checking function. Samgak has pointed out one. Another obvious optimisation is to return false if the word is longer than the number of available letters plus blanks. In the end, these are all micro-optimisations and you will end up checking your whole dictionary.

You said you have considered using a trie. That's a good solution, in my opinion, because the structure of the trie will only make you check relevant words. Build it like this:

- Sort the letters of each word, so that "triangle" and "integral" will both become "aegilnrt".
- Insert the sorted word into the trie.
- Where you would place the end-marker in a normal trie, you place a list of possible words.

If you were looking for exact anagrams, you would sort the word to check, traverse the trie and print out the list of possible anagrams at the end. But here, you have to deal with partial anagrams and with blanks:

- Regular traversal means you take the next letter of the word and then descent the corresponding link in the tree,if it exists.
- Partial anagrams can be found by ignoring the next letter without descending in the trie.
- Blanks can be dealt with by descending all possible branches of a trie and decreasing the number of blanks.

When you have blanks, you will end up with duplicates. For example, if you have the letters A, B and C and a blank tile, you can make the word CAB, but you can get there on four different ways: CAB, _AB, C_B, CA_.

You could get around this by storing the result list in a data structure that eliminates duplicates, such as a set or ordered set, but you would still go down the same paths several times in order to create the duplicates.

A better solution is to keep track of which trie nodes you have visited with which parameters, i.e. with with remaining unused letters and blanks. You can then cut such paths short. Here's an implementation in pseudocode:

```
function find_r(t, str, blanks, visited)
{
    // don't revisit explored paths
    key = make_key(t, str, blanks);

    if (key in visited) return [];
    visited ~= key;

    if (str.length == 0 and blanks == 0) {   
        // all resources have been used: return list of anagrams        
        return t.word;
    } else {
        res = [];
        c = 0;

        if (str.length > 0) {
            c = str[0];

            // regular traversal: use current letter and descend
            if (c in t.next) {
                res ~= find_r(t.next[c], str[1:], blanks, visited);
            }

            # partial anagrams: skip current letter and don't descend
            l = 1
            while (l < str.length and str[l] == c) l++;

            res ~= find_r(t, str[l:], blanks, visited);
        }

        if (blanks > 0) {
            // blanks: decrease blanks and descend
            for (i in t.next) {
                if (i < c) {
                    res ~= find_r(t.next[i], str, blanks - 1, visited);
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

(Here, `~` denotes list concatenation or set insertion; `[beg=0:end=length]` denotes string slices; `in` tests whether a dictionary or set contains a key.)

Once you've built the tree, this solution is fast when there are no blanks, but it gets exponentially worse with each blank and with larger letter pools. Testing with one blank is still reasonably fast, but with two blanks, it is on par with your existing solution.

Now there are at most two blanks in a Scrabble game and the rack can hold only up to seven tiles, so it may not be as bad in practice. Another question is whether the search should consider words obtained with two blanks. The results list will be very long and it will contain all two-letter words. The player may be more interested in high-scoring words that can be played with a single blank.

Comment: Thank you for the trie code. I'll try that when I have time.
I'm already filtering length when doing the initial SQL query.
While there are only two blanks, searching based on existing letters on the board would mean more blanks could be added to the search.